# jQuery get data attr from each and then perform count up animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to adjust a script I found on another stackoverflow question. Basically I want to be able to get the data attribute which is the count number and count from zero up to that number for each instance of that div.

Basically I'm trying to loop through each div element and make a variable of the data-attribute and then perform the count animation on that respective element.

My HTML:

```
  <div class="count_item" data-count="5000">0</div>

  <div class="count_item" data-count="444">0</div>

  <div class="count_item" data-count="6666">0</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
$(".count_item").each(function(i) {

  var count_val = $(this).data('count');

  $("body").append(count_val);
  console.log(count_val);

$({countNum: $(i).text()}).animate({countNum: count_val}, {
  duration: 8000,
  easing:'linear',
  step: function() {
    $(i).text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
  },
  complete: function() {
    $(i).text(this.countNum);
    alert('finished');
  }
});
});
```

I can't workout why if you look at the console it's getting two of the values and then it errors before the third. Help appreciated.

**Working example**: http://jsbin.com/yenunijemo/2/

Comment: `$(0)` or `$({countNum: ''})` look like useless selectors. What for are they here?

Comment: first argument of `each` is index, not element. Code shown really doesn't make a lot of sense and has multiple problems. Suggest you start over. No need to even use `animate` when all you need is a simple timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `i` is not what you expect it to be (it is index of each `.count_item` in the selection array, but not the element in itself). An easy way to fix that would be to define a variable (e.g.: `$this`) that will contain the element that you are working with, and replace `i` with that variable.

If you try the following code, it will work fine:

```
$(".count_item").each(function(i) {

    var count_val = $(this).data('count');
    var $this = $(this);

    $("body").append(count_val);
    console.log(count_val);

    $({countNum: $this.text()}).animate({countNum: count_val}, {
        duration: 8000,
        easing:'linear',
        step: function() {
            $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
        },
        complete: function() {
            $this.text(this.countNum);
            alert('finished');
        }
    });
});
```

You can see it working on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nqn09dd0/1/